# NULLIF() function doesn't work with WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The actual result of the following Query is NULL

```
select semid from programvariantterm where programvariantid = 240
```

But when I try the following statement, it gives 0 rows:

```
declare @semid int
set @semid = -1
select semid from programvariantterm 
where programvariantid = 240 and semid = nullif(@semid,-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing `NULLIF` and `ISNULL` a little bit.

Your statement would work with the following `ISNULL`:

```
where programvariantid = 240 and @semid = ISNULL(semid,-1)
```